# New to symfony 5- Error "No route Found" for Form in PUT method

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

i'm learning to use Symfony right now, and i'm having an issue with the routing system. I'm currently trying to edit a "Pin" using a form. So here is what I have in my controller so far for the update of a "Pin".

```
/**
 * @Route("/pins/{id<[0-9]+>}/edit", name="app_pins_edit", methods="GET|PUT")
 */
public function edit(Request $request, Pin $pin, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{

    
    $form = $this->createForm(PinType::class,$pin,[
        'method'=>'PUT'
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success','Pin successfully updated');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');
    }

    return $this->render('pins/edit.html.twig', [
        'pin' => $pin,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

And the error I have is this one when I try to update a Pin : "No route found for "POST"Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, PUT)".

I'm assuming it's because I wrote "methods="GET|PUT"" in my route. And this is what I actually need. But I keep having this error.

PS : With the createForm I have a hidden input in the form like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"
```

That is supposed to be read by symfony as "I want the put method" but doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for reading this ! And thank you for helping if you do!

PS : If you need more information or more code i'll be happy to share it with you.

Comment: Does your hidden field is _inside_ form?

Comment: @Justinas yes it is !